# Hook into the loop via a plugin, and output something after every X post?

Tags: loop

I have a plugin where I want to output ads after X number of posts on the home page. The home page is step 1, but things like archives should be possible too once I get the code for the home page.

How do I hook in to post loops and say something like "after every loop, increment a counter, and then if the counter = my number, output an ad". I can write all the logic for this code myself, but where to hook/implement my code is confusing.

Comment: You want to add it through the `the_content` filter? Can you post what you tried so far? Are you going to publish this plugin or is it just for your own homepage?

Comment: This is part of a very large, complicated code plugin. It's for serving ads, and it's already in place and live on many customers sites. the_content sounds fine. I just want to output a shortcode after specific post counts. For example, on the home page, put ads after posts 1, 3, and 5. All I need to know is how to hook into that location, then I can use the_content to add something below the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following:

### Method 1:

We can inject the ads via the `the_post` action, in the main loop:

```
add_action( 'loop_start', 'wpse_141253_loop_start' );

function wpse_141253_loop_start( $query )
{
    if( $query->is_main_query() )
    {
        add_action( 'the_post', 'wpse_141253_the_post' );
        add_action( 'loop_end', 'wpse_141253_loop_end' );
    }
}

function wpse_141253_the_post()
{
    static $nr = 0;

    if( 0 === ++$nr % 4 )
        echo '<div> -------- MY AD HERE ------- </div>';
}

function wpse_141253_loop_end()
{
    remove_action( 'the_post', 'wpse_141253_the_post' );   
}
```

### Method 2:

We can also inject the ads via the `the_content` filter, in the main loop:

```
add_action( 'loop_start', 'wpse_141253_loop_start' );

function wpse_141253_loop_start( $query )
{
    if( $query->is_main_query() )
    {
        add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_141253_the_content' );
        add_action( 'loop_end', 'wpse_141253_loop_end' );
    }
}

function wpse_141253_the_content( $content )
{
    static $nr = 0;

    if( 0 === ++$nr % 4 )
        $content .= '<div>------- MY AD HERE -------</div>';

    return $content;
}

function wpse_141253_loop_end()
{
    remove_action( 'the_post', 'wpse_141253_the_content' );   
}
```

Hopefully you can modify this to your needs.

Comment: I'll test this and let you know. Thanks for the detailed answer! I'll be sure to vote up and mark as solved if this works for me.

Comment: I see that you have left a little code on method 2 though. I don't think I need to use the loop_end functions, do I?

Comment: Too bad I can't vote up your answer, not enough points yet. It worked for me using your second method.

Comment: Ok, great. I think it's a good house-keeping rule, to clean up everything in the end. So that's why I added the loop_end part ;-)

Comment: Right, but in method two, there is no function wpse_141253_the_post, maybe you meant wpse_141253_the_content ?

Comment: And I notice you use the stackexchange ID as part of the function, that's very nice of you for most users so as not to duplicate function names.

Comment: @Branndon Thanks for spotting the misprint. I updated the answer.